# How to update specific index value of array in php laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm trying to create add to cart function, and the product is stored inside an array. The array is like this:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "product_id" => "Produk-0036"
    "quantity" => "2"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "product_id" => "Produk-0037"
    "quantity" => "3"
  ]
]
```

My question is how to update the quantity if product_id already exist inside the array?

```
$get_cart = Cookie::get('user_cart');
if(isset($get_cart)) {
    $cart_array[] = json_decode($get_cart);
}

$cart_array[] = ["product_id" => $request->product_id, "quantity" => $request->quantity];
$cart_json = json_encode($cart_array);
$cart_cookies = Cookie::forever('user_cart', $cart_json);
```

Using the code above will add new index in the array instead of updating the quantity of already exist product

Thanks

Comment: you may get some idea from this. ( the cart is in session there ). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69977302/products-showing-up-twice-in-php-array/69977954#69977954

Comment: @DebasisRath ah! thanks, It works for me. I just need to change the session to cookies

Comment: Good to know Catto, 1 like for that answer would be encouraging for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need update product quantity before **Cookie::forever**.

You can refer my suggest:

```
$cart_array = [
        ["product_id" => "Produk-0036", "quantity" => 2],
        ["product_id" => "Produk-0037", "quantity" => 3],
    ];
    
foreach($cart_array as &$cart)
{
  if(isset($cart["product_id"]) && $cart["product_id"] == $request->product_id) 
  {
      $cart["quantity"] += $request->quantity;
  }
}
$cart_json = json_encode($cart_array);
$cart_cookies = Cookie::forever('user_cart', $cart_json);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function

Try something like this:

```php
$cart_array = [
    [
        "product_id" => "Produk-0036",
        "quantity" => "2"
    ],
    [
        "product_id" => "Produk-0037",
        "quantity" => "3"
    ]
];

$product_id = "Produk-0036";        // product_id to update

$cart_array = array_map(function ($item) use ($product_id) {
    if ($item["product_id"] == $product_id) {
        $item["quantity"] = "5";    // update quantity
    }
    return $item;
}, $cart_array);

var_dump($cart_array); // OUTPUT: updated array
```